# Python Celery: How do I join task results out of order?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I have a simple project where I create a bunch of chunks of work that's not related to each other, create tasks, pass them to Redis, and have a number of workers spread out over a Docker Swarm chew through the queue of long-running tasks. When the workers finish they dump their completed work in an NFS share and send back a text value to the Celery client.

I'm using celery.result.ResultSet's .join() function on the resultset array of asyncresult objects. The join() includes a callback that (for now) simply prints the result.

My problem is join() blocks until it receives each asyncresult value in the order it was given. My swarm is made up of a number of hosts that are vastly different machines, and it's important to me to have results come back as they finish, not in order or once they are all complete.

Is there a way via Celery to properly trigger a callback function as tasks are finished? I've looked at a lot of examples online and seems like my only option is to try my luck with asyncio, but Python is not exactly my strong suite.

Func for creating tasks and ResultSet obj:

```
def populateQueue(encodeTasks):
r = ResultSet([])
taskHandles = {}

for task in encodeTasks:
    try:
        ret = encode.delay(task)
        r.add(ret)
        logging.debug("Task ID: " + str(ret.task_id))
        taskHandles[ret.task_id] = ret 
    except:
        logging.info("populateQueue fail: " + str(task.traceback))

logging.info("Tasks queued: " + str(len(taskHandles)))
return taskHandles, r
```

Part of main() which waits for results:

```
        frameCountTotal = getFrameCount(targetFile)
        encodeTasks = buildCmdString(targetFile, frameCountTotal, clientCount)
        taskHandles, retSet = populateQueue(encodeTasks)

        logging.info("Waiting on tasks...")
        retSet.join(callback=testCallback)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question:

ResultSet has another method called join_native(), which I think uses more specific API calls to the broker as long as that broker is one of several known products (RabbitMQ, Redis, etc). Celery's documentation just says that it gives better performance if you meet the broker requirement. What the docs don't say is that it allows for out-of-order returns (at least on Redis, haven't tried RMQ).